# XPath following-sibling functionality without axes

Tags: xpath

I have no possibility to use `following-sibling` axis in my XPath.
How can I get the same functionality in XPath without using axes? Is it real?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add sample XML/HTML document and explain what element(s) you need to select

Comment: What library/application are you using and what subset of XPath _does_ it support?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are using an XQuery 1.0 implementation without full axis support? If that's the case you can write `following-sibling::x` as

```
let $x := . return ../x[. >> $x]
```

If you're not using XQuery 1.0 without full axis support, then I think we need to know what you are using.